# Salesforce Long Text Area

Tags: setup

This is a pretty simple question but I can't seem to find an answer. I have created a long text area in Salesforce and set the visible lines to 2:

[image]

But when viewing the field in a lead record - all rows are shown:

[image]

Referring to the documentation for the visible lines attribute:

> For long text area fields, set the number of lines to be displayed on edit pages.

So I can set the number of visible lines on the edit page no problem, but how do I set the number of visible lines for the text area long field on the lead details page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you [can't use Text Area (Long) within formulas](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br4g) you could create a before insert/update trigger to copy a shortened value to another custom field that you only display on the view layout?

The approach might be a bit heavy handed and will also muck up the inline editing.

Comment: Daniel's correct, and the unspoken response to your question is that there is no way (that I'm aware of) to control how much of a longtext field is visible on a standard page layout. 

A simple solution might be to put that field in its own section - you can then maximize it only when required.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a workflow to fire whenever this field changes and have a field update that sets the first xxx characters to another field that you can then show on the page layout.

WF Criteria = IsChanged(field)
Field Update = Formula : LEFT(LongTextArea, 2000)